# Looking meaning of calc(1.25rem + 0.30vw)

Tags: css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I saw calc(1.25rem + 0.30vw) in bootstrap and I didn't get what it means. I am using bootstrap for the design a responsive page on a website. Please help

I am expecting meaning of it with calculations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZVbu.png)

Comment: Have you had a look at the MDN explanation which covers this? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 1):

`rem` units are calculated relative to the font-size of the root `<html>` element (by default this is usually `16px`). `vw` elements are calculated relative to the viewport width, where `1vw` is 1% of the viewport width.

So assuming that the root font-size is `16px` and your viewport width is `1280px`, `calc()` function would be calculating

```
(1.25 * 16px) + (0.003 * 1280px) = 20px + 3.84px = 23.84px
```

You can read more about the different CSS units here: [CSS values and units (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Answer (score 1):

**calc()** is one of the few CSS functions. As the name indicates it will calculate a value, allowing for simple math in CSS.

**rem** stands for Root EM which is the root `font-size`. By default, the UA (User Agent = default stylesheet of the browser) of most browsers will use 16px. That means, that 1.25rem equals 1.25 times 16px or 20px in total.

**vw** stands for view width it is a percentage of the viewport's width (the width of the browser). Assuming you run a browser in full screen on a 1920x1080px monitor, the viewport width will be 1920px. That equals 5.76px on that view width (1920 x 0.003).

Taking the calc function into account the width will mean 20px + 5.76px = 25.76px. However, as those are responsive units, the value will change on different screens and root font-sizes.

Comment: "view width" — or "viewport width".

Answer (score 0):

It means that the `font-size` will be calculated dynamically, based on the client's viewport width plus the root element's size multiplied by 1.25. For example, if you have a viewport width (the available width where you can view the website content) `1000px`, you will get `3px` by specifying `0.3vw`. Then check the `html` element `font-size` property. The default is `16px` if you don't find it, then you will get `20px` (`1.25rem`). Finally, you'll have `20px` + `3px` = `23px`.

If you don't want to do all of these calculations, you can just check the Computed tab in Inspect window to see the actual value calculated for your element.

Here you have different things to be clarified,

- `font-size`, it's an obvious one, it defines the size, usually in pixels, like `font-size: 16px`.
- `rem`, it's the root element size (root-em, em comes from typography, you can think of it as the width of the letter M), and it's a relative unit. The root element is the `html` element, and the default value for `rem` is `16px`. But if you have explicitly specified it,
  `html {font-size: 10px}` then `1rem` will be `10px`, and `1.25rem` will be `12.5px`.
- `vw`, viewport width, means that 1% of the viewport if you have `100vw` then you will get all the available width in pixels from the device viewport. If you resize your browser window or open the website in your mobile app you can specify `50vw`, so you will always get half of the viewport without worrying about the size in pixels.
- `calc()` method, this just does the calculation explained above in your CSS.

Comment: it was 0.30vw not 30vw